# JavaScript Array Syntax

Tags: javascript, arrays

```
var selectColumns = new Array();
selectColumns[0] = { TableName: "DeploymentRosterView", ColumnName: "ArrivedOn" };
selectColumns[1] = { TableName: "DeploymentRosterView", ColumnName: "DepartedOn" };
selectColumns[2] = { TableName: "DeploymentRosterView", ColumnName: "RoleType" };
selectColumns[3] = { TableName: "DeploymentRosterView", ColumnName: "AdjusterFirstName" };
selectColumns[4] = { TableName: "DeploymentRosterView", ColumnName: "AdjusterLastName" };
```

The above works to create my array in JavaScript, but is there a more graceful way to write the above? Like an Object Initializer? Just wondering

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can create it inline:

```
var selectColumns = [
    { TableName: "DeploymentRosterView", ColumnName: "ArrivedOn" },
    { TableName: "DeploymentRosterView", ColumnName: "DepartedOn" },
    { TableName: "DeploymentRosterView", ColumnName: "RoleType" },
    { TableName: "DeploymentRosterView", ColumnName: "AdjusterFirstName" },
    { TableName: "DeploymentRosterView", ColumnName: "AdjusterLastName" }];
```

Answer (score 1):

You could create an array like:

```
var selectColumns = [
    { TableName: "DeploymentRosterView", ColumnName: "ArrivedOn" },
    { TableName: "DeploymentRosterView", ColumnName: "DepartedOn" },
    { TableName: "DeploymentRosterView", ColumnName: "RoleType" },
    { TableName: "DeploymentRosterView", ColumnName: "AdjusterFirstName" },
    { TableName: "DeploymentRosterView", ColumnName: "AdjusterLastName" }
];
```

Comment: Please note - this is not JSON. That is an array literal with object literals. JSON has very specific syntax, which this is not. See http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc4627.txt?number=4627

Comment: rule of thumb - if it is a string its JSON if it is a JS object then its just a JS object

Comment: @missingno - I've always kinda understood that there are no "json objects", but your comment really solidified it for me...thank you, and +1 on your last answer :)

Comment: @Chris you know, the syntax is the same, instead of `var selectColumns = ` and quotes for keys.

Comment: Two downvotes is not a "terrible reaction". The answer is technically incorrect, that's what the downvote mechanism is **for**. You were given a reason for the downvotes, and you could have taken that chance to correct the inaccuracy (I would have removed my down vote had you done so), instead you're defending the inaccuracy with a shrug and a "it's close enough" (which is a further inaccuracy)? Too bad.

Comment: @balkon_smoke - I +1'd you, so you have a net increase of 8 for your efforts :)

Comment: @balkon_smoke - though in reading the rest of the comments, in the future you should just fix simple mistakes like this, rather than arguing.  Learning from from more experienced devs is the real value of this site.  Like what I learned from missingno's comment.

Comment: @balkon - we all have those days :)

Answer (score 1):

You could restructure it like so:

```
var selectColumns = {

  "DeploymentRosterView": {
    "ColumnNames": ["DepartedOn", "RoleType", "AdjusterFirstName", "AdjusterLastName"]
  }
};

// Loop through all views
for (view in selectColumns)
{
  var v = selectColumns[view].ColumnNames;
  alert('Column names for "' + view + '" is: ' + v.join(', '));
}​
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use some tricks to avoid retyping some things in this particular case

```
var columnNames = ["ArrivedOn", "DepartedOn", "RoleType", "AdjusterFirstName", "AdjusterLastName" ];

var selectColumns = columnNames.map(function(colName){
    return { TableName: "DeploymentRosterView", ColumnName: colname };
});
```

Do note that map is not available by default on old browsers (but variations of it are very popular in libraries and shims)